# How can I separate starches from plant based milk (lentil milk)

Tags: equipment, food-science, lentils, starch, plant-based

I made decanted plant-based milk using lentils (nut milk bag), I'd like to remove the starches from the milk. I have tried several methods so far and a couple I have not tried such as enzymatic reduction of starches using alpha-amylase but here is what I have tried so far :

- I let the milk sit until the starches sink to bottom and pour off the milk, the milk seems to still contain a lot of starches.
- I have tried gelatinization but that seems to make the entire liquid viscous.
- I have tried fermentation but that doesn't seem to help much here unless someone can recommend a specific culture to remove the starches.

Has someone done this successfully?

Comment: I don't think that the amylase route is promising. Best case, you'll end up with a solution of sugars instead of starch, and you'll have to devise a method to get rid of the sugars (unless you have a use case where starches are a problem but sugars aren't).